# Android Recyclerview Filtering Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder error

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to filter my recyclerview with a searchbar. Whenever i call                 `myAdapter.filter.filter(newText)` from my searchbars `onQueryTextChange` i get this error:

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid
> view holder adapter positionViewHolder{8bf63e2 position=6 id=-1,
> oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1 scrap [attachedScrap] tmpDetached no parent}
> androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

Adapter class:

```
class FriendListAdapter(val items : ArrayList<FriendListItem>, val context: Context) : androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter<FriendListViewHolder>(),Filterable {

    var filterItems = ArrayList<FriendListItem>()

    init{
        filterItems = items
    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return filterItems.size
    }
    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return position
    }

    override fun getFilter(): Filter {
        return object : Filter() {
            override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): FilterResults {
                val charSearch = constraint.toString()
                if (charSearch.isEmpty()) {
                    filterItems = items
                } else {
                    val resultList = ArrayList<FriendListItem>()
                    for (row in items) {
                        if (row.userName.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT).contains(charSearch.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT))) {
                            resultList.add(row)
                        }
                    }
                    filterItems = resultList
                }
                val filterResults = FilterResults()
                filterResults.values = filterItems
                return filterResults
            }

            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: FilterResults?) {
                filterItems = results?.values as ArrayList<FriendListItem>
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }

        }
    }

    // Inflates the item views
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): FriendListViewHolder {
        return FriendListViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.friendlist_item, parent, false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: FriendListViewHolder, position: Int) {

        //holder?.profileImage?.background = items[position].profileImage
        holder?.userName?.text = filterItems[position].userName
        holder?.level?.text = "Seviye "+filterItems[position].level



  if(filterItems[position].gender == 0){
            holder?.gender?.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.male_icon))
        }else{
            holder?.gender?.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.female_icon))

        }

        if(filterItems[position].isOnline){
            holder?.isOnline?.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.online_circle))
        }else{
            holder?.isOnline?.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.offline_circle))

        }



    }


}

class FriendListViewHolder (view: View) : androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    // Holds the TextView that will add each animal to
    val itemContainer = view.friendlist_item_container

    val userName = view.friendlist_item_username_textview

    val level = view.friendlist_item_level_textview
    val isOnline = view.friendlist_item_isOnline
    val profileImage = view.friendlist_item_profile_image
    val gender = view.friendlist_item_gender

}
```

without implementing filtering and filterItems list my recyclerview is working fine. must be something wrong on filtering part, or the way `class FriendListViewHolder` implemented causesthis